# Clicking div inside of div bypass javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm not entirely sure how to word this in a search engine. Say I have the following:

```
<div class = "outer-box">
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
</div>
```

I really want to define a jquery event for when you click the outer box, and a different even for when you click the inner box within the outer box, without triggering the outer event (or at least nullifying it)

Is there any way to check in the outer-box event if I also triggered the inner-box event so that I can then just not execute the code? Or any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: in jquery event.stopPropagation() [http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner box will get the event first so just `return false;` at the end of it to not propagate the error. Also, assuming you defined the event handler as:

```
handleEvent(e)
```

then you can stop propagation thusly:

```
handleEvent(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Hot diggity that's much easier than I thought, apologies for the very basic question

Answer (score 1):

Bind  event to the parent container and use stopPropagation.

```
$('.outer-box').on('click', function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);

    if($target.hasClass('inner-box')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly too, to be fair I just went ahead and accepted the first answer!